# RESTeasy 3.0.16 missing something (RESTEASY003210)

Tags: java, tomcat, resteasy

I have this all working in one webapp and not working with another and cannot for the life of me see what the difference is.

RESTeasy 3.0.16 (also tried 3.0.13)
Tomcat 7.0.67

Libraries: resteasy-servlet-initializer, resteasy-jaxrs, resteasy-jackson2-provider

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>REST Service</display-name>
</web-app>
```

ServiceApplication.java

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ServiceApplication extends Application { }
```

ServiceInterface.java

```
public interface ServiceInterface {
     @GET
     @Path("/ping")
     @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
     public Response ping();
}
```

Service.java

```
public class Service implements ServiceInterface, Serializable {    
    @Override
    public Response ping() {
        return NoCacheResponseBuilder(Response.Status.OK).entity("PING").build();
    }
```

Calling http://localhost:8080/webapp/api/ping causes a RESTEASY003210 exception.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it always the way that you find the answer just after you post (after spending 3 days on this...)

Service.java was wrong. It needed to be:

```
@Path("/")
public class Service implements ServiceInterface, Serializable {

    @Override
    public Response ping() {
        return noCacheResponseBuilder(Response.Status.OK).entity("PING").build();
    }
}
```